# What happens if we read from a table while a transactional update is happening on that table?

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions

Suppose I have a table called Record.

With transaction X, I will add 1 million new Records and also modify some existing Records.

While transaction X is running and not yet completed, if I query the Record table, will I see the new records? Also, will I see the updates to the existing Records?

Comment: I think that depends on `transaction isolation level`.

Comment: Are you familiar with what [MVCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) is?

Comment: @tadman , no I am not familiar with it.

Comment: Reading up on that would probably explain a lot of things. The InnoDB engine isn't as good as Postgres at handling this, but it does an okay job. The [InnoDB documentation on MVCC](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-multi-versioning.html) explains from a MySQL perspective.

Comment: @tadman, thanks. So it really depends on the type of engine that is being used.